# Fabric.js function to move object from point A to B

Tags: javascript, animation, fabricjs

i am trying to make function that would take x,y coords and time to which currently selected object would move over some time period. So for example ObjectA on position 0,0 would move to position 50,75 over 5 seconds. It would slowly animate its movement by small bits till it reaches end coords

function move(x,y,time){
...
}

Anyone done something similar, or is there any function for this that i missed? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that ends up on this thread, [Yondaru's followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36735411/1807003) has a working example answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Fabric.js` [animation API](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2#animation).

rect.animate('top', 45, {
  duration: 1000,
  onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
});

If you wanna compress several animations into one, you could use something like this:

```
function animateFabricProps(item, properties, values, options) {
  var opts = options || {};
  for (var i= 0; i < properties.length; i++){
    item.animate(properties[i], values[i], opts)
  }
}
```

Or better yet, extend the Fabric js object with a "animateSeveral" method, that doesn't need to take an `item` param.