# Fabric.js animate object/image

Tags: javascript, animation, fabricjs

Hello everyone this is code that ive been working with. It moves an object from A to B. What i am trying to do is have multiple points to which it would move. So from starting position A -> B, then from B -> C and so on. Maybe have some variable which would contain sets of coordinates, which would get fed into some animate function as parameters. But anything i tried resulted only in executing the last command, so it would move straight from A -> C, ignoring B. Any advice/demo appreciated.

Javascript

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('scene', { backgroundColor: 'green'});

var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
    width: 30
  , height: 30
  , fill: 'red'
  , left: 30
  , top: 0
});

canvas.add(triangle);

function animateTop() {
  triangle.animate('top', '+=55', {
    duration: 1000,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
  });
}

function animateLeft() {
  triangle.animate('left', '+=100', {
    duration: 1000,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
  });
}

function fireAnimation() {
  animateTop();
  animateLeft();
}

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    fireAnimation();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="scene" width="400" height="400" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the animation functions don't block each other, so when your `fireAnimation()` function runs, it's starting both animations at the same time, and each animation change is applied on each frame, which means that both animations occur simultaneously.

One way to resolve this would be to chain the animation calls using the animation `.onComplete` event. Doing this *might* lock you into a bit of a hellish situation if you need to update the order of your animations.

Given that you proposed perhaps having a list of animations to apply one after another you may be served better by creating a generic function that applies animations based on an input list of animation parameters like this (explanation in comments in code):

```
function startAnimationQueue(animationQueue){
    // queues up the animations for the shape

    var runningDuration = 0; // variable that adds up the animationQueue durations
    for (var i=0; i<animationQueue.length; i++){
        var animationDefinition = animationQueue[i];

        // Create a closure around the animationDefiniton so that each setTimeout gets sequential animationDefinition inputs
        var fn = (function(animationDefinition){
            return function(){
                triangle.animate('left', animationDefinition.left, {duration: animationDefinition.duration, onChange:canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)})
                triangle.animate('top', animationDefinition.top, {duration: animationDefinition.duration, onChange:canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)})
                // Note: you can animate additional attributes here if you want, just add additional attributes to the objects in
                //   the animationQueue list. You could also have one of those inputs be the object to be animated in case you want
                //   to animate multiple objects using the same queue.
                };
            })

        // Create the timeout that will apply the transformations sequentially
        // If you want you could set the window.setTimeout to a variable that you could destroy if you need 
        // to interrupt the animation queue after you create it (but before it finishes)
        window.setTimeout(fn(animationDefinition), runningDuration);

        // set the next setTimeout duration to be .duration later than the previous one
        // this makes the second animation fire after the first one completes
        runningDuration += animationDefinition.duration;
    }
}

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {

    // I put the canvas init stuff in here because of (I think) a failed race condition or something that caused
    // your original method to fail in Chrome
    window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('scene');

    window.triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
        width: 30
      , height: 30
      , fill: 'red'
      , left: 30
      , top: 0
    });

    window.canvas.add(window.triangle);
    window.canvas.renderAll();

    // Create a list of animations to apply
    var animationQueue = [
        {"left": "+=0", "top": "+=100", "duration": 1000},
        {"left": "+=55", "top": "+=0", "duration": 2000}

    ]

    // Apply the animations in sequence using window.setTimeout
    startAnimationQueue(animationQueue);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the list. @Yondaru, I recommend you look into state machines, they are the best approach for handling animation sequences.

Comment: @nickvans, Thanks a lot, works like charm. And could you maybe tell me what would you do  if you had image uploader for this canvas and you would want to assign a list of commands to each of the uploaded images?

Comment: First add an additional attribute to each animationQueue object that will store the fabric object for the image once you create it. `{"fabricShape": newlyAddedShape, "left": "+=0",...` Change the closure function to use `animationDefinition.newlyAddedShape` instead of `triangle` In the completed event for your uploader (the event fired when the upload is successful) simply create a new animationQeue list for that object and pass it to the startAnimationQueue function.

Comment: Also don't forget to mark my response as answering your question (green check under the voting arrows) to help others find the answer to similar questions if they have them.

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn't be a problem. I've never used sprite animations, but it appears they have a top/left attribute just like the rest of the fabric objects, so you should be able to animate their position the same way. For the text bubble you'd want to either group the bubble with the sprite (using fabric.Group) or simply apply the same animation to both the sprite and the bubble. For the bubble I'd recommend using an SVG path like this one: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Speech_bubble.svg (view page source to see SVG code)